# Python statsmodels GLM - log likelihood of null model

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, likelihood, statsmodels

I have an issue when calculating log-likelihood for null model to double-check GLMResults.llnull parameter:

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.llnull.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.llnull

First I generate some data:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

loc = 2
scale = 3

b0 = 2.5
b1 = 0.03

size = 500
x = np.arange(0,500,0.01)
y = gamma.rvs(a = (np.exp(b0 + b1*x) - loc)/scale, loc = loc, scale = scale, random_state = 124)
```

Then I run gamma GLM:

```
mdl = sm.GLM(y, sm.add_constant(x), family = sm.families.Gamma(link = sm.families.links.Log()))
mdl_results = mdl.fit()
mdl_results.summary()
```

Obviously it works fine with Pseudo R-squ. (CS) equal to 1.000.

When I print out the llnull parameter:

```
mdl_results.llnull
```

I get the value:

```
-16631197.140949667
```

However when I want to double-check this value running null model, I cannot recreate it:

```
null_mdl = sm.GLM(y, np.repeat(1,50000), family = sm.families.Gamma(link = sm.families.links.Log()))
null_mdl_results = null_mdl.fit()
null_mdl_results.summary()
```

And now printing:

```
null_mdl_results.llf
```

gives completely different value:

```
-648684.3846193118
```

Comment: This does not look like a crossvalidated question. My first guess is that the scale is not updated when calculating the null in the full model. There could also be numerical problems because y has large numbers.

Comment: confirmed null loglike in full model uses full model `scale`. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9025  bug or feature? scale is treated as auxiliary parameter in GLM (one-parameter linear exponential family).

Comment: At this point it is a feature. `llnull` is currently only used to compute pseudo-rsquared. Most pseudo-R2 definitions in the literature are either scale free or use the scale from the full model. (statsmodels pseudo-rsquared for GLM is Cox-Snell but without a changing scale effect but the GLM docs don't mention that.)